# How to select entity many value?

Tags: entity-framework

I want to two column value in entity but I

dont selected.

How to solve select problem.

Try code:

```
var t1= dbcontext.Entities.Student.Select(c=>c.Number , a=>a.branchcode).
```

I error branchcode area.

But ı select number and branchcode.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
var t1 = dbcontext.Entities.Student.Select(c => new { Number = c.Number, Branchcode = c.Branchcode });
```